# cakephp save() creating blank entry to database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I am new to CakePHP, i am creating simple form to add/edit/delete post as it is explain on its official website, my issue, while adding post to database it is not saving data,it is creating blank entries to database

Here is Code for Postscontroller.php

```
    <?php
    class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('Session');




    public function add() {
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Post->create();
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        //debug($this->Post->validationErrors);
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
   }




 }
    ?>
```

Here is Code for Model Post.php :

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {

 public $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    )
);
}
?>
```

Here is code for View add.ctp :

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

can anyone suggest me what is causing blank entries to database ?

Comment: can you try this:debug($this->request->data) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `add.ctp` :

The form name is Post not post...

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

Comment: what it has to do with my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/core.php` file change the `debug label to 2`.`(Configure::write('debug', 2))` and try saving again. The model name should be Post in the form. Please check the post data before saving.

`debug($this->request->data)`;

```
exit;
```

Comment: i already change debug value to 2 and data array, it is what it looks like :
Array
(
    [post] => Array
        (
            [title] => asd
            [body] => asd test
        )

)